# How I can change a For loop to PLINQ syntax?

Tags: c#, plinq

I have a real problem with my code which is very slow and make it useless. I must deliver my results next week and by this code it takes more than 4 weeks!
As this code calculates fluid motion, we deal with more than 1 million cells. Therefore, my main **For loops** (order is important) has heavy calculation and right now every output takes 12 mins.
Imagine I need atleast 5000 output !

**Can anyone help me to improve the calculation speed?
or
Could you help me to understand how to change For loop to PLINQ syntax?**

*I'm frustrated*

```
//implementation of time nt = 1,000,000
    For (int t=0; t<nt; t++)
    { 
// main calculations, 2 dimensional   
    for (int i = 0; i < nx; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < ny; j++)
            {
                if (!Cells[i, j, 0].IsVirtual)
                {
                    // calculate x velocity - nx = 1,000,000 & ny = 1,000,000
                    // calculate y velocity
                    // Data for each (i,j) affect (i+1,j+1)
            }
         }
     }
    }
```

Comment: The first question will be can the calculation be done in parallel, as you mention order is important, so does one run through loop affect the next run? Also where is most of the time spent, the actual calculation or are you accessing objects to do the calculations

Comment: The code is very big but the most calculation is in two For loops and for each output (it has a bigger For loop which works a time) these two internal For loops should be done. These For loops calculates velocities for 1 million points.
Other For loops have not effective on the speed.

Comment: Do you have a hot path from profiling your current implementation?  Using parallel processing can give you a marginal speedup, but optimizing actual implementation might produce additional improvements.

Comment: Are you sure that each inner part is independent of other inner parts?

Comment: I agree with @GregC, perhaps your algorithm is the problem, not the implementation. Have you looked at numerical methods for solving the problem?

Comment: If this algorithm relies on lots of floating-point computation, then GPU-side processing might be your best bet.  Also, if using Intel processors with Hyper-Threading, for best performance don't spin up as many computations as HTs, but only as many as you have cores.

Answer (score 1):

To be able to use PLINQ you need to change your two dimensional for loop into a sequence of elements that can be processed (e.g. `IEnumerable<T>`). You can create the x and y values as a sequence using this code:

```
var indices = Enumerable.Range(0, nx).SelectMany(
  _ => Enumerable.Range(0, ny),
 (x, y) => new { X = x, Y = y }
);
```

You can then filter the sequence of indices using `Where`:

```
indices.Where(index => !Cells[index.X, index.Y, 0].IsVirtual)
```

Then you can project the indices to create the results using `Select`:

```
var results = indices
  .Where(...)
  .Select(index => new { index.X, index.Y, Result = ... });
```

When you have converted your code into this form and ensured that it works on a small dataset you can use PLINQ to run the computation in `Select` in parallel by inserting `AsParallel`:

```
var results = indices
  .Where(...)
  .AsParallel()
  .Select(index => new { index.X, index.Y, Result = ... })
  .ToList();
```

In your question you talk about the importance of order. You can ensure that the results produced are kept in the same order as the input indices by using `AsOrdered`:

```
var results = indices
  .Where(...)
  .AsParallel()
  .AsOrdered()
  .Select(index => new { index.X, index.Y, Result = ... })
  .ToList();
```

However, the "body" of your for loop is still executed in parallel in no particular sequence. It is only the final results that are ordered when the list is created by `ToList`. If the importance of order you mention means that you have mutable state that is used in the body of your for loop then you will not be able to use PLINQ.

This approach to using PLINQ is not particular efficient. If you have to process 1,000,000 cells then this code will allocate 1,000,000 objects to store the indices for the cells. However, it seems that processing time and not memory allocation and garbage collection is what is limiting your computation.

You can avoid the overhead of the allocations if you use something like [`Parallel.For`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.for%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to parallelize your computation but then you will be using TPL and not PLINQ.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The For loops should be in order because the results of every iteration is necessary for the next iteration. So they should be done one by one. In this way I cannot use TPL and PLINQ. so what I should do for increasing speed?

Comment: @user3803849: It is hard to tell because I have no information about your computations. To parallelize your computation you need to logically find a way to partition the work so multiple threads can do it parallel. TPL and PLINQ can only assist you in doing the work when you have figured a way to partition the work. It cannot magically come up with this partition for you. If you realize that your algorithm requires that the cells are processed in strict sequence you might instead focus on optimizing the computations inside the for loop.

Comment: my calculation is in the way that for example velocity at (i,j) need to calculate velocity at (i+1,j+1). So everything should be in order. My code takes time because it needs to calculate very points and so much time. For instance at least 10 million times for a system with 1 million cells (two dimensional cells). How can I optimise this kind of calculations? Some of my friends who write in C++ use GPU implementation to speed up their calculations.

Comment: If your requirement is that rows should be calculated in sequence you can use a normal for loop for the rows in inside this loop you can have a "parallel" loop using TPL or PLINQ for the cells within the row. Because the number of cells in a row is much larger the number of cores you will still get maximum utilization of your cores.

Answer (score -1):

use below code, you can use your collection instead list.Let me know if you need any help:

```
List<string> lst = new List<string>();
foreach (var item in lst.AsParallel())
{
    foreach (var data in item)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, actually, I couldn't understand your comment

Comment: what is "nx" in your code or give me whole code i will convert it into plinq.

Comment: The main part of my code that has the slowest speed is the mentioned two For loops. 
nx= 1000,000 - ny=1000,000 and in the For loop there is a big part of velocity calculations.